# Merge tables and extract names

Tags: excel, join, merge, vlookup

Will try to make as succinct as possible. I have an excel table on 2 Different Sheets.

On Sheet1 I have a table with headers:Zodiac Element Duality    Quadraplicity.

One Sheet2 I have a list of people with the 12 signs of the Zodiac(12 columns with a list of names underneath each Zodiac).

What I need to do is select "Air" from the Element Column, which will then select the Zodiac(s) on that table, (which is a column to the left). Then go to the second sheet and extract the appropriate columns in a list of names, so i have a list of people who have the "Air" attribute. I can then repeat for other attributes.

All help appreciated!
Daniel

Comment: Does each Zodiac only have one element?

Comment: The data on Sheet2 is not well structured. If you use a simple table with columns for Name and Zodiac instead of twelve columns, you can use Power Pivot to create a relationship between the two tables, build a pivot table and filter on the related element.

Comment: Thanks teylyn, that actually sounds very obvious now. 

@gordatron, each Zodiac has 4 elements.

Comment: @DanieloKeeffe each one has 4 or there are four elements and each sign has one (as per the data i found for my suggested answer)?

Comment: @gordatron Yes as per your answer each Zodiac has one assigned element, 4 elements in total.

Comment: Poverpivot not available for Excel 2016(office ed) but data not complex (thus far) so solution is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2 would probably be better structured something like this:

[image]

With formulas like:

[image]

This uses a vlookup (https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) to get data from sheet 1 abased on the sign. you can then use standard filtering to view people by elements.

But if yo plan on using filters and you are doing vlookups then "format as table" (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-an-Excel-table-6789619F-C889-495C-99C2-2F971C0E2370) is very useful:

[image]

Here i have called the table on sheet 1 "signs"

I can then use the table name in my formula on sheet 2 (also formatting it as a table):

[image]

I can then use the table functionality to filter by element (https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e):

[image]

Fromtehre as teylyn says you could add a pivot table (with or without power pivot depending on how complex the relationship is - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413497(v=sql.110).aspx)

[image]

And you can add slicers to simply select various properties / dimensions (https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-slicers-to-filter-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB):

[image]

Note: if you use pivot tables or PowerPivot hen you will need to refresh the pivot table when you add or remove data from your source tables (https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Refresh-PivotTable-data-6d24cece-a038-468a-8176-8b6568ca9be2). if you have used a "format as table" excel will know if you have added or removed columns and rows, if you don't use format as table you will need to change the data source to include new rows or columns in your source data.

Comment: Thanks this is Perfect :)

Comment: @DanieloKeeffe FYI.. i am pretty sure PowerPivot is in all version of Excel 2016 (here how to turn it on: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Start-the-Power-Pivot-add-in-for-Excel-a891a66d-36e3-43fc-81e8-fc4798f39ea8) you don't need it for this but its a super cool technology :D